# Possible to use knitr cache chunk in interactive rmarkdown doc?

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown, shiny-server

I've noticed that when I have an Rmd with `runtime: shiny` in the YAML, code chunks don't seem to be read from cache.  I'm wondering if using the shiny engine for rmarkdown just doesn't support chunk caching, or am I doing something wrong?

Example Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Cache test"
output: html_document
---

```{r cache=TRUE}
Sys.sleep(10)
```
````

If you run this 5 times, only the first time will take 10 seconds, and any subsequent run will be fast.

But if you add the `runtime: shiny` option to the YAML, then every single run will take 10 seconds.

(PS question: any better way to test whether or not code chunks cache is being used?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into the same problem where, in `runtime: shiny`, the `cache` switch was ignored.

Nowadays there is a workaround, using `runtime: shiny_prerendered` and `context="data"` with `cache=TRUE`:

````
---
title: "Cache test"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r,context="data", cache=TRUE}
Sys.sleep(10)
```
````

this behaves as expected; on the first run, rendering takes 10 seconds; on all subsequent runs, the cached chunk is used.

Comment: Yes, this shiny prerendered is a great addition by rstudio :)

Comment: @DeanAttali If it works, don't forget to accept the answer.